# golang inheritance to implement backbone like collection / model

Tags: inheritance, go, data-structures, collections, embedding

I am looking into golang as my new goto language for my web-backend. My current language there is PHP, where I implemented a datastructure resembling the Backbone Collection/Model structure.

## excursus Collection / Model

This means I have a `Collection` containing multiple `Models`. `Models` have an `attributes` dictionary for storing the actual "public data". `Collections` have multiple convenience methods operating on the array of `Models` (sort, getByIndex, getByMatchingParameter, etc). `Models` also have their share of convenience methods.

In daily life there will be 90% of "things" that are represented the same way. For example I can store an `Address` the same way I store my `User`. Having an `AddressesCollection` containing my `Addresses` I can simply ask my `AddressesCollection` to give me all `AddressModels` where `city=Berlin`. And implementing this matching in my base class I can do the logically same thing on my `UserCollection` giving me all my Users which are deactivated by `deactivated=true`.

But sometimes (10%) I need a special method. `getGeoData` for `Addresses` for example. Now, in my oop-world, I can simply create a new class extending my `BaseModel` adding my method and use my extended class everywhere where my base class was used.

## My "i simply don't get it"

How does this work in Go. I read a lot introductions into embedding / composition. But simply do not get my head around this.

This is where I stand, keep in mind this is my playground for learning the "inheritance" concept, not for having a production ready Collection / Model implementation.

[GoPlayground](https://play.golang.org/p/clrGldR46j)

What I get is that I haven't "understood" how to write a "generic" method accepting not-quite-inherited types. I have the feeling that I have to use an interface there somewhere to get this "inheritance"/"extended class" feeling. But my current use of this is... well...

But maybe I am completely wrong in my concept of implementing my desired structure that way in go at all? Maybe there is a much more elegant way. Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: The absolute best possible advice I can give, and I cannot say this strongly enough: *write Go like Go.* Do not try to emulate patterns you've used in other languages. That way leads only to madness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I really didn't understand the go-way of doing this.

The buzzwords that helped me to move on:

- ORM
- go generate

Projects that look like solving my issue:

- [GORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm)
- [SQLBoiler](https://github.com/vattle/sqlboiler)

Thanks for the answers, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close to getting it right, but you have mixed up multiple different things.

Complete example: https://play.golang.org/p/wpj82QRVUP

1. Type embedding

So you have two models `User`, `Address` and they both share common fields and maybe methods. This is a good reason to create a common struct for both: `Model`, as shown in the link above. **All three structs are of different types**.

2. Collections

You can have a collection of interfaces or collection of defined types. So when to use which?

If you have a collection of addresses, defined the type of follows: 
`type AddrCollection []*Address`. And then implement whatever method you want on `AddrCollection` type.

If you have a collection of models, similarly define `type ModelCollection []*Model`, but then passing `Address` to the `ModelCollection` would require to "extract" the embedded type.

If you have a collection of something, then define a collection of interfaces (`DescriberCollection` in the example), but then you would not have `GetByAddress()` defined on it, and it would only exist in `AddrCollection`

3. Interfaces

They have no fields they only define method signatures to be implemented. In Go interfaces are normally accepted and never returned, that gives u a benefit to have clean and goal-oriented design. Interfaces is a way to allow other users (or other packages) to use your packages/libraries in a way that they do not need to implement your types, but rather a certain methods. They can reuse your defined types, or they can plug-in their own implementations of the interface. So what is an interface, it is a way of saying: **here are the set of method signatures, as long as you implement them you can use my package**

Comment: Thanks for the input! I fear we are on different pages at some point. 
I tried to condense the Source for the post, but now I think this complicated things. [Full Code](https://github.com/huehnerhose/learning_go/tree/mocked_version)
My current problem is [here](https://github.com/huehnerhose/learning_go/blob/mocked_version/datastructures/collection.go#L18). I want a generic get(byId) on my "collection". And I don't get rid of the feeling of working "against the principals of go" here

Comment: I suggest you try asking in Go Slack channel, what you did is far away from idiomatic go and it's principals. You have a higher chance to be set in correct direction if you ask around in that channel.